# Giving multiple file names as link to Tkinter GUI in python and opening with default application

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
#python version 2.7.11

import os
from Tkinter import *

fileName = "Nothing"    #fileName is required so that the callback function can link the current file name with button click

def callback(event):
    #os.startfile() works only on windows machine
    os.startfile(fileName) #opens the fileName with its default application (in my case a pdf viewer)

def makeLink(file):
    global fileName
    fileName = file
    link = Label(textbox, text=fileName, fg="blue", cursor="hand2")
    link.pack()
    link.bind("<Button-1>", callback)

oldDir = os.getcwd()
newDir = os.chdir("pdf folder") #pdf folder contains some pdf files

root = Tk()
textbox = Text(root)
textbox.pack()

allFiles = os.listdir(os.getcwd()) #makes a list of files present in current directory

for file in allFiles:
    makeLink(file)

root.mainloop()

os.chdir(oldDir)
```

I want to select the files of a folder (in above code it's pdf folder) containing some pdf files and display them as a link in GUI window. When pressed on the link, the file should open with it's default application (so the pdf file should open with default pdf viewer). My code is displaying the file names of every file in the "pdf folder" as link. But on clicking on every link, the last file of the folder is opening. Can someone correct the code so that every link opens it's own file. I searched everywhere but found nothing on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what you have coded so far. You're making `fileName` global and then setting `fileName = file` where the last assignment will be the last item in your loop. So, this is why it is opening the last file. If you want a user to be able to select options from these I'd suggest a combobox or some other widget that takes the list of filenames as the options. You can then bind on `<<ComboboxSelected>>` to call your `makeLink` function.

you should really also rename `file`. `file` is a built in.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast, I didn't know about combobox. It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can surely be done by combobox but when i have many pdf files then every file is placed in a combobox which is not a good way to interact. 
Here I have taken two count variables ---- one is global count and one localCount. The localCount is required to remember the count of which file is to be opened.

```
from Tkinter import *
import os

def callback(count):
    os.system("open "+fileNames[count])

def makeLink(files):
    localCount = count
    link = Button(frame1, text=(count , files), bg="light blue", cursor="hand2", command=lambda: callback(localCount))
    link.pack()    

oldDir = os.getcwd()
newDir = os.chdir("pdf folder")
fileNames = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

root = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

count = 0

for files in fileNames:
    makeLink(files)
    count += 1

root.mainloop()

os.chdir(oldDir)
```